# Tensorflow quantization: No such package

Tags: python, tensorflow

Trying to quantize neural network. I ran the following command in the tensorflow repo directory

`bazel build tensorflow/tools/quantization/tools:quantize_graph`

And got the error :

> ERROR: Skipping 'tensorflow/tools/quantization/tools:quantize_graph':
>   no such package 'tensorflow/tools/quantization/tools': BUILD file not
>   found on package path WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed. ERROR:
>   no such package 'tensorflow/tools/quantization/tools': BUILD file not
>   found on package path INFO: Elapsed time: 0.081s INFO: 0 processes.
>   FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow recommends that you use the `transform_graph` tool instead. The documentation is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms#eight-bit-calculations).